# Who has my axe?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In the Stocks screen, I can see that there is an axe somewhere. It's not forbidden, but my woodcutter won't pick it up. Is there any way to see where it is?

Comment: I only know Gimli has his.

Comment: I thought he gave it away at the council of Elrond?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes: hit <kbd>tab</kbd> to switch from group to individual mode in your stock screen, then you can use the arrow keys to navigate to the axe and <kbd>z</kbd> to zoom to it.

Comment: Aha! Turned out I had a dabbling axedwarf walking defending my fortress.